# Adding custom indentation for C# code in Visual Studio (not VS Code)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have C# code as below:

```
Log.Step("step 1");
int x = 10;
int y = 20;

Log.Step("step 2");
int a = 10;
int b = 20;
```

I want the editor to auto-format those lines as below:

```
Log.Step("step 1");
    int x = 10;
    int y = 20;

Log.Step("step 2");
    int a = 10;
    int b = 20;
```

After every Log.Step method, I want to be able to indent the next lines of code till a newline is entered. Is there a way I can define indentation rules in VS to do so?

Comment: Why [?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_whys)

Comment: I doubt you can do that in any setting.  That's a pretty arbitrary indentation

Comment: There is the option of creating a portable, custom editor settings, ie. `EditorConfig` -> (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-portable-custom-editor-options?view=vs-2019)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your indentation format is very specific, but there is a approach using `{ }`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Log.Step("step 1");
    {
        int x = 10;
        int y = 20;
    }

    Log.Step("step 2");
    {
        int a = 10;
        int b = 20;
    }
}
```

Is not a "identation" rule, but maybe this can help you

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion. that helps!